# How to split a string on the first occurrence of one of multiple substrings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Given strings

```
s1 = "abcfoodefbarghi"
```

and

```
s2 = "abcbardefooghi"
```

How can I split s1 into "abc" and "defbarghi"
and s2 into "abc" and "defooghi"
That is: split a string into two on the first occurrence of either one of strings "foo" or "bar"

I suppose this could be done with `s.split(/regexp/)`, but what should this regexp be?

Comment: Look at this question:

[Split string once in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression in this way:

```
var match = s1.match(/^([\S\s]*?)(?:foo|bar)([\S\s]*)$/);
/* If foo or bar is found:
  match[1] contains the first part
  match[2] contains the second part */
```

Explanation of the RE:

- `[\S\s]*?` matches just enough characters to match the next part of the RE, which is
- `(foo|bar)` either "foo", or "bar"
- `[\S\s]*` matches the remaining characters

Parentheses around a part of a RE creates a group, so that the grouped match can be referred, while `(?:)` creates a non-referrable group.

Comment: This works and is well explained. In the end I needed to match the **last** occurrence and get the splitting string back, so I did `/^([\S\s]*)(foo|bar)([\S\s]*?)$/`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/foo|bar/,"\x034").split("\x034")
```

idea is replace the first occurrence with a special(invisible) String, and then split against this string.