# ignore second delimiter while spliting string into array

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows-

```
 roger::)
```

I need to split into two string as `roger` and `:)` . I am using the following

```
"roger::)".split(":")
```

But this forms three array elements,namely `roger`,`[empty]` and `)` although what i need is two array elements as `roger` and `:)`.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character)

I tried using the following link but the console prints `undefined` for `"roger::)".split(/_(.+)?/)[1]`

Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test case looks limited, perhaps you can just use *match*:

```
'roger::)'.match(/[^:]+|:\)/g); // ['roger', ':)']
```

Maybe that suits, or not:

```
'roger::):another:test'.match(/[^:]+|:\)/g); // ["roger", ":)", "another", "test"]
```

Comment: Could you confirm the second part of my answer is not working? It works for me, but in an old FF version and I cannot test in another browser right now.

Comment: Both statements in your answer return what I consider correct results in Safari 6.05 and Firefox 24, but testing in older browsers would be much more beneficial. I only suggested alternatives as they don't use look ahead so will suit older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookaheads. It will split on a `:` if followed by `:`.

```
"roger::)".split(/:(?=:)/);
```

However perhaps this is what you want instead. Split on `:` unless it's a followed by `)` which would be an happy face.

```
"roger::):another:test".split(/:(?!\))/);
```

Comment: `"roger::)".split(/:(?=:)/);` gives a single array element.However I wanted two array elements.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain I just pasted your code in the console and I get two elements? Which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using it for smiley itself.. testing across firefox,chrome..
`"roger::):another:test".split(/:(?!\))/);` refuses to accept anything except `:)`

Comment: @MayurBuragohain That's wierd. Works for me in FF and on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @MayurBuragohain Could you post the result of `JSON.stringify("roger::):another:test".split(/:(?!\))/));` ?