# javascript finding a string in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need a loop to check if a string contains "\n".

```
   
var content = "Hello \n bob \n ben je op deze \n world \n bobert",
```

what i need is a javascript (node.js) script that checks the String content if it contains "\n" and if it does

it needs to split the on the "\n" char and then print it like this

```
<content>Hello </content><br />
<content>bob </content><br />
<content>ben je op deze </content><br />
<content>world </content><br />
<content>bobert</content><br />
```

Comment: Not sure of node.js, but you can use split() in javascript

Comment: There is similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring/1789952#1789952 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Node.js but in javascript it can be done using split()

```
var content = "Hello \n bob \n ben je op deze \n world \n bobert",
content_array = content.split("\n");
content_array.forEach(function(entry) {
    document.write("<content>'+entry+'</content><br />");
});
```

Comment: it should be "<content>"+entry+"</content><br />" at last line

Answer (score 2):

```
var content = "Hello \n bob \n ben je op deze \n world \n bobert";
var arr = content.split("\n"); 
var str = '';
arr.forEach(function(val){
 str += '<content>'+val+'</content><br />';
})

$("div").html(str)
```