# splitting by first occurence of comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a message of the form:

`var message = 'hello.there, "how are you, doing"`'

Which needs to be split by the first occurrence of `','` such that I have two objects namely `'hello.there'(param 1)` and `"how are you, doing(param 2)"` such that `param 2` should be a list of `arguments(length=1)`and spaces should be preserved?

I have tried something like
`var param2 = message.split(/,(.+)/)[1]`

but that would result in param2 being a string instead of list of arguments.

Comment: `"should be a list of arguments..."` please, clarify this part, which kind of list and arguments?

Comment: To add another example Lets say I have a message, `var mess = hello.there, "how are you, doing", 12` then split should happen so that param 2 obtained should be a list consisting of `how are you, doing and 12 of length 2 and not 3.

Answer (score 2):

Just find the first comma, then substr by that:

```
const pos = message.indexOf(",");
const param1 = message.substr(0, pos);
const param2 = message.substr(pos);
```

Or if `param2` should be an array of the other strings seperated by a comma:

```
const [param1, ...param2] = message.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find the index of the first `,`, slice the string at that index, and then split the second slice by `,`:

```
var i = message.indexOf(',');    //find the index of the first ,
var param1 = message.slice(0,i);    //param1 is the slice from 0 to i
var param2 = message.slice(i+1).split(',');    //param2 is the slice from i+1 splitted at ,
```

By the way, there are some other methods as well for splitting an array by first occurrence of a token. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript) might interest you.