# Javascript split sentence only by first concurrence

Tags: javascript

I need to split a sentence, but only by a first concurrence. For ex:

`"hello my dear hello blah blah".split('ello')`

Expected result:

`["h", "o my dear hello blah blah"]`

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string once in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript)

Comment: build your solution arround `String.prototype.indexOf`

Comment: @Ivar. It was by mistake. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match `ell` with a non greedy search and take only the groups left and right from it.

[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) does not work here, because it works global for the string.

```js
console.log("hello my dear hello blah blah".match(/^(.*?)ell(.*)$/).slice(1));
```

Using a variable (mind special characters!) and a `RegExp` constructor.

```js
var string = 'ell',
    regexp = new RegExp('^(.*?)' + string + '(.*)$');

console.log("hello my dear hello blah blah".match(regexp).slice(1));
```

Comment: Thats exactly I needed. Could you please tell one more thing - how to pass a variable instead of `ell`?

Comment: @gizmo are you kidding? :/

Comment: @sjahan I wish, but regex is not my pal at all. I tried similar solutions , but couldnt find a way

Comment: Oh I must use a RegExp constructor... I thought its possible just with useual expression (if that supposed to called expression)

Comment: I think it doesnt work if signs are used, like `+`. Could you confirm? `var string = '+ell'` and `console.log("h+ello my dear h+ello blah blah".match(regexp).slice(1));`

Comment: that's wha i wrote *"mind special characters!"*. `+` is a quantifier in regular expression. to quote it, you need to add a backslash in front of it, like `\+`.

Comment: That's correct, because your search is becoming a part of the regular expression, and `+` is a regular expression, so you'd have to escape it like so `\\+ell`

Comment: Thanks. But if I dont know will there be a `+` or no, adding slash won't make any errors?

Comment: it makes, because some other characters, like linefeed or new line needs a backslash in front of it.

Comment: @AnonymousSB, the double backslash quotes the backslash, not the quantifier.

Comment: Ok, so I just check with `startsWith('+')`, but this still seems fragile. Thanks anyway~

Comment: @NinaScholz That’s not the case, try it for yourself with just one backslash, I did.

Comment: @gizmo you may be better off with Teun’s solution of just using slice to avoid the headache of using user input inside a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the first index of the occurance of your search string, then split the original on that index, like so:

```
const sentence = "hello my dear hello blah blah"
const searchValue = 'ell';
const index = sentence.indexOf(searchValue);
const result= []
result.push(sentence.slice(0, index));
result.push(sentence.slice(index+ searchValue.length));
// result = ["h", "o my dear hello blah blah"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace with something that will not be in the string, and split by it :

```js
console.log( "hello my dear hello blah blah".replace('ello', '\0').split('\0') )
```