# Split String from substring for first match

Tags: javascript, string, split

Below is an example of a String that I want to split it to 3 parts from a substring

```
test01String001s
```

Examples:

- example_1 subString ==  "0"

  *res: [ "test","0","1String001s" ]   - test**0**1String001s*
- example_2 subString ==  "st"

  *res: [ "te","st","01String001s" ]   - te**st**01String001s*
- example_3 subString ==  "01s"

  *res: [ "test01String0","01s", "" ]   - test01String0**01s***
- example_4 subString ==  "t"

  *res: [ "","t","est01String001s",  ]   - **t**est01String001s*

I try to resolve it via

```
 var string='test01String001s'
 var keyword="01"
 console.log(string.split(keyword));
```

output:

```
     ["test","String0","s"]  instead of [ "test","01","String001s"]
```

or

```
 var string='test01String001s'
 var keyword="0"
 console.log(string .split(keyword, 2));
```

output

```
 ["test","1String"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string once in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878703/split-string-once-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually not completely. I just add a answer in a comment but I think that we are close

Comment: To keep the separator, you can use `[s.slice(0,i), separator, s.slice(i+1)]`

Answer (score 1):

To get 3 parts I wouldn't use `split`, but use some logic

```js
const mystring = 'test01String001s'
const sp = ['01','1','t','st', '1s']

sp.forEach(item=>{
  let idx=mystring.indexOf(item)
  let result=[]
  if(idx===0){
    result.push('')
    result.push(item)
    result.push(mystring.slice(item.length))
  }else if (idx+item.length ==mystring.length){
    result.push(mystring.slice(0,idx))
    result.push(item)
    result.push('')
  }else if(idx!=-1){
    result.push(mystring.slice(0,idx))
    result.push(item)
    result.push(mystring.slice(idx+item.length))
  }
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var string = "test01String001s";
var splitKey = '01';
var components = string.split(splitKey);
var array = ([components.shift(), components.join(splitKey)]);
array.splice(1, 0, splitKey);
console.log(array.join());
```

Output: **`test,01,String001s`**

Comment: @NakosKotsanis Happy to help you. If it helps you, Please accept it

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const test = 'test01String001s';
const key = "t";
const re = new RegExp('(.*?)(' + key + ')(.*)');
const result = test.match(re, "regex");
result.shift();

console.log(result);
```

So this regex match is returning an array of:

(.*?) - anything before key

(' + key + ') - key

(.*) - anything after key

Unfortunately it also returns the whole matched word, so I used shift to remove first match from array.

Answer (score 0):

I have written one function named `split`. It will work fine if splitter is found in a string, otherwise it will return `[string, splitter, string]`

For example:

`string = 'test01String001s` and `splitter=01` now give output `["test", "0", "1String001s"]`

if `splitter = "apple"` it will return `["test01String001s", "apple", "test01String001s"]`

If you want to return empty value when splitter not found in a string,
simply add `if(splitter_index < 0) return ["", "", ""]` before current return statement line in `split` function.

Please check all examples below and anyone think any changes needed please comment down.

```js
let string = "test01String001s"

function split(string, splitter) {
    let splitter_index = string.indexOf(splitter);
    
    return [string.slice(0, splitter_index), splitter, string.slice(splitter_index+splitter.length)];
}

// example_1
console.log(split(string, '0'));

// example_2
console.log(split(string, 'st'));

// example_3
console.log(split(string, '01s'));

// example_4
console.log(split(string, 't'));
```